# Controling pytests fixtures report in case of failures

Tags: python-3.x, pytest

I have a bunch of tests that use randomly generated data as input.  To ensure the failures are repeatable, I've organized them as follows:

```
import random
import pytest   

@pytest.fixture
def seed():
    return random.getrandbits(32)


def test_foo(seed):
    # seed the random number generators, and generate random data
    # test foo

def test_bar(seed):
    # seed the random number generators, and generate random data
    # test bar

def test_baz(seed):
    # seed the random number generators, and generate random data
    # test baz
```

This way in case of failure, pytest reports the value of the `seed` and I can temporarily change the `seed()` fixture to return that particular value, fix the failures and then revert it back.  (There are more elegant ways to do so probably.)

One issue with the above structure is that there is a lot of code repeated in each test for generating the random data.

I, therefore, decided to refactor the test module as:

```
import random
import pytest   

@pytest.fixture
def seed():
    return random.getrandbits(32)

@pytest.fixture
def stimulus(seed):
    # seed the random number generators and generate random data
    return data 


def test_foo(stimulus):
    # test foo

def test_bar(stimulus):
    # test bar

def test_baz(stimulus):
    # test baz
```

Now the tests are repeatable still, in the sense that if `seed()` fixture returns (or rewritten to return) the same value we get the same test results.  However, in case of failure, pytest prints out the value of `stimulus` which is typically too long to fit on the screen.  (Plus it would be much harder to change `stimulus()` to return exactly the same data.)

Is there a way to tell to pytest that "in case of failures print out the value of the last fixture, i.e., `seed` and not the first fixture `stimulus`"?

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do (if you are ok to see the output of `stimulus` as well) is that let the `stimulus` fixture return `(seed, data)` (and adjust your test functions accordingly) and in the pytest command include the switch `--showlocals`. This way, you will see the value of the fixture, just that now it shows the value of `seed` as well..